# Making beaver builder module settings chose able?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a beaver builder extension and every thing is working fine, but the issue is that I want to give some select able options to client so that he/she can choose their respective options and we can provide functionality as per their selection.

For Example, I want to give 2 options. Option one, select your post type ? Options are "post", "custom post" ... now if he/she selects "post" i want to show some options only post relevant but if he/she selects "custom post" I want to show options related to custom post. I did this thing in visual composer but unable to do in beaver builder so far.

Here is some of mine code:

```
'sections'      => array( // Tab Sections
        'general'       => array( // Section
            'title'         => __('Section Title', 'fl-builder'), // Section Title
            'fields'        => array( // Section Fields
                'select_field'   => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Show Filter or Not?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'no_of_posts' => array(
                    'type'          => 'my-custom-field',
                    'label'         => __('Provide your desired number of Posts', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => '8'
                ),
                'no_of_cols' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Provide your desired number of Cols', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-2',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('2', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('3', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-3'      => __('4', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-4'      => __('6', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_overlay' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to Show Overlay?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_lightbox' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to Open Image in lightbox?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_lightbox_link' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Link Icon in Lightbox?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_title' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Post Title?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_title_link' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to use Link in Post Title?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_content' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Post Content?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_link' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Post Link?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
```

The point is again simple: I want to show my options only when some other relevant option is selected.

For example, if user selects option "post" then this should be done

```
'no_of_cols' => array(
                'type'          => 'select',
                'label'         => __('Provide your desired number of Cols', 'fl-builder'),
                'default'       => 'option-2',
                'options'       => array(
                    'option-1'      => __('2', 'fl-builder'),
                    'option-2'      => __('3', 'fl-builder'),
                    'option-3'      => __('4', 'fl-builder'),
                    'option-4'      => __('6', 'fl-builder')
                )
            ),
```

Means I want to show options for selection only if post is selected etc. Hope I conveyed my problem clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm perhaps too late for this!

But you simply need to use 'toggle'.

```
'select_field'   => array(
  'type'          => 'select',
  'label'         => __('Show Filter or Not?', 'fl-builder'),
  'default'       => 'option-1',
  'options'       => array(
    'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
    'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
  ),
  'toggle' => array(
    'option-1' = array(
      'fields' => array('another_field')
    )
  )
),
'another_field' => array()
```